# object has at least one TRUE then return true in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an object, object values are boolean (true or false). If object has only one `true` value then return `true` otherwise return `false`.

I tried this:

```
var obj = {1001: false, 1002: true};

var keys = Object.keys(obj);

var filtered = keys.filter(function(key) {
    return obj[key] === true
});

console.log(filtered)
```

Comment: `more than TRUE` Eg, `prop: 'foo', prop2: true` should result in `false`, is that what you mean?

Comment: {1001: true, 1002: true} ==> FALSE

Comment: {1001: false, 1002: true,1003: false} ==> TRUE

Comment: {1001: false, 1002: false,1003: false}  ===> FALSE

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
var filtered = Object.values(test).filter(item => item).length === 1;
console.log(filtered)
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to iterate over all values regardless, in order to see if they're all true.

If the values are guaranteed to be booleans, one option would be to add them all up. If the result is equal to the number of properties, or 0, return false, otherwise return true:

```js
const checkValid = obj => {
  const values = Object.values(obj);
  const truthyValues = values.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  return truthyValues > 0 && truthyValues !== values.length;
};
console.log(
  checkValid({1001: true, 1002: true}),
  checkValid({1001: false, 1002: true,1003: false}),
  checkValid({1001: false, 1002: false,1003: false}),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Plain and simple 
Working code is attached, to check result just increase or decrease the number of true in Object

```
    const ob = {1001: false, 1002: false, 1003: true, 1005: true};

var hasTrue = Object.keys(ob).some(k => ob[k]);
var bb = Object.values(ob).reduce((a, item) => a + item, 0);
if(bb > 1){
    alert("False");
}else {
    alert("true");
```

```js
const ob = {1001: false, 1002: false, 1003: true, 1005: true};

var hasTrue = Object.keys(ob).some(k => ob[k]);
var bb = Object.values(ob).reduce((a, item) => a + item, 0);
if(bb > 1){
  alert("False");
}else {
alert("true");
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You could count with a short ciruit for more than one `true` value.

```js
const one = object => {
    let count = -1;
    return !Object.values(object).some(v => v === true && ++count) && !count;
};

console.log(one({ 1001: false, 1002: true }));               //  true
console.log(one({ 1001: true, 1002: true }));                // false
console.log(one({ 1001: false, 1002: true, 1003: false }));  //  true
console.log(one({ 1001: false, 1002: false, 1003: false })); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to check the object is `some()` function built in Javascript which is built for exactly this purposes.

Definition: *The some() method tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function. It returns a Boolean value.*

Usage in your case:

```
const checkValid = obj => {
  var obj = {1001: false, 1002: true};
  return Object.values(obj).some(element => element === true)
};
```

First, we use `Object.values(obj)` to get the values of the object as an array. Then, we go through the array and check if it has at least one `true` value.

More on `some()` function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct your request, then please try to use:

```
const obj = {1001: true, 1002: false};
const values = Object.values(obj);
const result = values.includes(true) && values.every((val) => val === true) ? true : false;
```

or as another one:

```
const obj = {1001: true, 1002: false};
const result = Object.values(obj).some(val => val === true);
```